# File path broken in Xcode. (lots of ../../../../)

Tags: xcode

My Xcode suddenly can't get file path properly.

If I create a new file, the path looks pretty weird, like so:

[image]

**What I expect is**:

[image]

**Clues I have so far:**

1. This happens on all projects.
2. This happens when I create a new file or re-locate an existing file.
3. This doesn't happen on a new project. But if I close the project and reopen it, it happens again.

**Environment:**

OS: macOS Catalina Beta 4

Xcode: 10.2.1, 10.3, 11 Beta 4 (yeh, I tried it all)

Comment: All group is set to "Relative to Group". `path` in `project.xcproj` is exactly the same as the screenshot. My current workaround is modifying the path in `project.xcproj` after I create a file.

Comment: I'm guessing this is caused by Catalina Beta 4 because this seemed to start happening after I upgraded to Beta 4. 

Comment: I've been having the same issue since updating to Catalina Beta 4. Similarly, updating xcode versions did not help. My workaround is to click on the file, remove reference, then in finder drag the file back into its group in xcode and the file path will be fixed.